# How to implement RecyclerView item color change

Tags: android, xml, kotlin

Please tell me, I want to do something like tabs using RecyclerView and Buttons as in the picture. And I need it to be implemented like tabs. That is, when you click on one button, it changes the text, and when you click on another, it also changes the color, and the previous one returns the old text

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways to handle the selected item color/text change in a RecyclerView. One way is to add a color flag or selected item flag to the RecyclerView item's data class. When the text button is clicked, the isSelected flag is set to true for the clicked item and reset to false for the previously selected item. When the color button is clicked, the color is updated directly.

After updating the item properties, calling notifyDataSetChanged() updates the RecyclerView and reflects the changes visually.

In your case you can also handle this as below-

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val item = items[position]
        holder.textView.text = item
        holder.textView.setOnClickListener {
            // Change the text and color of the clicked item or button
            holder.textView.text = "Changed!"
            holder.textView.setTextColor(Color.RED)

            // Reset the text and color of the previous item
            val previousPosition = position - 1
            if (previousPosition >= 0) {
                val previousItem = items[previousPosition]
                val previousHolder = getItemViewHolder(previousPosition)
                previousHolder.textView.text = previousItem
                previousHolder.textView.setTextColor(Color.BLACK)
            }
        }
    }
```